# How do I return 0 or something else if min(list) raises ValueError?

Tags: python

I have a list value, `my_list`, that I would want to get its minimum value:

```
min_value = min(my_list)
```

This works fine if `my_list` is not empty but raises **ValueError** if the list is empty.

Is there any way I can return something else in a very *Pythonic* way if `my_list` is empty and also have the **ValueError** arrested without having to check with `if`(like shown below):

```
if my_list:
    min_value = min(my_list)
```

I want a one line thing. Something like:

```
min_value = min(my_list) or another_value
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.4, you can use the [new `default` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes):

```
min_value = min(my_list, default=0)
```

In older versions, a simple [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-conditional_expression) can be used:

```
min_value = min(my_list) if my_list else 0  # Empty lists evaluate to False
```

Comment: Poor me. This did it. Will accept in 9 minutes. So says SO.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is `min(my_list or [0])`

Comment: This will work and suppress the `ValueError` if I only want to return 0 but I guess it won't work if I want to return a string?

Comment: @Yax: It will work with any value instead of `0`. There's nothing that says `min` only works with numbers.

Comment: Assuming I want to return "Yes" if list is empty? That will return "Y". **Edit:** I get it now: `min_value = min(my_list or ['Yes'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
my_list = []
another_value = 555
print min(my_list) if my_list else another_value
```